# Flutter, couldn't get data from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I tried fetching data from cloud firestore using stream builder, but I get this error on `snapshot.data!.docs`. Error: "Null check operator is used on a null value"e. But it's not a null value cloud firestore has data. How do I solve this? What aree the other ways that I can use to get data from firestore.

```
 body: 
          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: firestore.collection('paymnet data').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return snapshot.hasData?ListView(
                 children:
                   snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
                     Map<String,dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                     return ListTile(
                       title: Text(data['amount']),
                       subtitle: Text(data['paid date']),
                     );
                   }).toList();
                 
                ):Container();
              })
```

Comment: Kindly check, firestore.collection('paymnet data').snapshots(). is the collection name spelling is correct. I think it should be 'payment data'.

Comment: Yes, makes sense but it's actually paymnet data.

Comment: Can you upload correct code?The Code snippet you uploaded seems missing some code.

Comment: Here you go. ( https://codeshare.io/N3bxVJ ) I've tried a few things to fetch data from firestore So, the code doesn't look good.

Comment: From the code you have provided I can see that you have defined a `getPaymentsdata()` method. Can you check if you are getting the data inside that method? Also can you just add a screenshot of the database from the Firebase console?

Comment: I tried printing the data using ```getPaymentsdata()``` method but instead of the data I got something like "firebase query dynamic>>> as output in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Your code syntax using `!(bang)` looks fine as per the official [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#:%7E:text=children%3A%20snapshot.data).

A quick check on data being `null` can be validated be printing the data values. As you are looping through the collection, there may be a possibility for some data values to be null.